# How to make N samples distributed over M threads where N >= M in jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a test scenario where I have a `Main.csv` file that contains data as

```js
Main.csv
    one.csv
    two.csv
```

and inside `one.cvs` I have data like

```js
one.csv
   one_one
   one_two
   one_three
   .
   .
   so on
two.csv
   two_one
   two_two
   two_three
   ....so on
```

Now I am using CSV data set config to read contents of `main.csv` and using loop controller to loop through `one.csv` to read contents using __csvRead() function and similarly for `two.csv`.
[image]

I am unable to execute contents inside `one.csv` in a concurrent manner
i.e if I have 10 lines in `one.csv`, one thread is picking up all the values of `one.csv` and executing 10 calls in a sequential manner which I want some 5 threads to distribute among themselves and execute in a concurrent manner.
Is it possible?